# How to fetch values from json response in python having a dictionary containing list of dictionary?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, python-requests, python-requests-html

I need to fetch a value like, if the animal is dog than i need its id

```
 {'findSomething': [{'Name': 'Andrew', 'id': '321Z4', 'animal': Dog }, {'Name': 'Andrew', 'id': '31Z45', 'animal': Cat }]}
```

Comment: res[0] knows its the first row , but in my case , I am not sure that animal will be on first row or other , thats why I ll check animal and fetch the corresponding id

Comment: Is Dog a string (in that case you missed the quotes), or is it an Object?

Comment: `res=your_dict.get('findSomething')`  `print([x.get('id') for x in res if x.get('animal')=='Dog'])`, assuming Dog is a string

Comment: According to my knowledge, JSON needs double quotes...

Comment: you can use `json.load/loads` to load json to a dictionary, or use `response.json()`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
data =  {'findSomething': [{'Name': 'Andrew', 'id': '321Z4', 'animal': 'Dog' }, {'Name': 'Andrew', 'id': '31Z45', 'animal': 'Cat' }]}
res = [x['id'] for x in data['findSomething'] if x['animal'] == 'Dog']
print(res) #['321Z4']
```